# Selecting logical vector elements based on certain conditions

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a situation where I would like to detect conditions between two logical, named vectors based on the TRUE / FALSE combination at each position in the vector. For example:

```
x <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
names(x) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
y <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
names(y) <- names(x)
```

For each element in these two vectors I want to detect 3 conditions:

- `x[i]` is `TRUE` and `y[i]` is `TRUE`;
- `x[i]` is `FALSE` and `y[i]` is `TRUE`,
- `x[i]` is `TRUE` and `y[i]` is `FALSE`.

The length of `x` and `y` are the same but could be longer than this example. I want to retrieve the name of the element for each condition and assign the element name to a new variable. For this example:

```
v1 <- "a"
v2 <- "b"
v3 <- "d"
```

In a longer version of these two vectors I might end up with something like:

```
v1 <- c("a", "e")
v2 <- c("b", "f", "g")
v3 <- c("d", "i", "k", "l")
```

What is the best vectorized way to do this. I think it is simple but I am unable to come up with the answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can efficiently use `split`, but before that, we need a single grouping index. Here is a possibility:

```
g <- x + y + x
split(names(x), g)
```

To understand the above grouping index, consider this:

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
y <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
x + y + x
#[1] 3 2 1 0
```

So you can see that 4 combinations of `TRUE` and `FALSE` are mapped to 4 integer values.

> Ah, so "a" get assigned to `T-T`, "b" to `T-F`, etc. But, why the `x + y + x`?? I don't follow adding `x` twice.

If you only do `x + y`, the result is only 0, 1 and 2. You won't be able to differentiate `T-F` and `F-T` as they are both 1.

---

[@thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail) offers a more readable way:

```
split(names(x), interaction(x, y, drop=TRUE))
```

---

**Update**

Ah... stupid me... Why did I bother creating `g`. I suddenly remember that we can pass a list to `f` argument in `split`:

```
split(names(x), list(x, y))
```

Note, internally in `split.default`:

```
if (is.list(f)) 
    f <- interaction(f, drop = drop, sep = sep)
```

Comment: Ah, so "a" get assigned to T-T, "b" to T-F, etc. But, why the x + y + x?? I don't follow adding x twice. OK, I see. That generates 4 distinct integers for the 4 situations, using the logicals as integers. Clever!!

Comment: Another example for interaction to help with - `split(names(x), interaction(x,y,drop=TRUE))` - might make it more interpretable than creating `g` via addition

Comment: Very nice! Thank you both very much!

Comment: impressed by the `x+y+x` logic. Nice ! +1 @ZheyuanLi

Comment: I chose a very poor example, unfortunately. In the case where I have x <- c(T, T, T, T, T) and y <- c(F, F, T, T, F), for example, I only find the T-F and T-T groupings. But, I would also like to detect that F-T and F-F have some kind of detectable absence (0 or NA, perhaps). In other words I want to be able to detect the groupings T-T, T-F, F-T, and F-F for any configurations of the two logical vectors. ??? How ???

Comment: Yes. And thanks. I also have a more brute force solution by looking at: as.character(unlist(result$FALSE.FALSE)), etc., for all 4 combinations, where result <- split(names(x), list(x,y)), but that is not as elegant as the solution you offer.